# No Access to Non-Greedy .*?

Tags: regex, stata, non-greedy

My text is:

```
999 blaw blaw blaw1 999 blaw blaw blaw
```

And I want to choose:

```
blaw blaw blaw1
```

Now, I could do this using:

```
([0-9][0-9][0-9] )(.*?)( [0-9][0-9][0-9])
```

But the problem is I can't use `".*?"` in what I'm using. Replacing `(.*?)` with `([^0-90-90-9]*)` would have worked if I didn't have the `1` replaces by the `blaw1`!

Any suggestions, I'm using Stata if it is relevant.

Comment: [`[0-9]{3}\s(.+)\s[0-9]{3}`?](http://regex101.com/r/zF4oA7/1)

Comment: `([0-9][0-9][0-9] )(.*?)( [0-9][0-9][0-9])` should work fine in Stata.

Comment: I wrote a script to use PCREs with Stata: http://shafiquejamal.blogspot.com/2012/12/stata-tip-using-perl-compatible-regular.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment by [hwnd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2206004/hwnd):

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input str60 text
"999 blaw blaw blaw1 999 blaw blaw blaw"
end

list

*----- what you want -----

gen extract = regexs(2) if regexm(text, "(^[0-9][0-9][0-9] )(.+)( [0-9][0-9][0-9])")

list
```

Also

```
... regexm(text, "(^[0-9]+ )(.+)( [0-9]+)")
```

From `help regex`:

> Regular expression syntax is based on Henry Spencer's NFA algorithm,
>   and this is nearly identical to the POSIX.2 standard. [*arguments*]
>   may not contain binary 0 (\0).

Other references are:

http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/regular-expressions/

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/regex.htm

Comment: @Unihedron What is that supposed to mean? Please be explicit when commenting answers.

Comment: If you are suggesting something like `[0-9]{3}` it won't work. Stata's regular expression feature is very basic. My answer already contains a complete example that actually works.

Answer (score -2):

Try following `(?<([a-z]*[0-9]? )*)`  I am not familiar with Stata but this working in Javascript implementation of regex

Updated to consider backtracking.

Comment: Apparently Nothing works in Stata. I tried your code in notepad++ and it works nicely but not in Stata.

Comment: What if you just do ` ([a-z]*[0-9]? )*`  because I realized that first part is redundant

Comment: Actually it should be + not * other wise this will match single digit between spaces. 

So correct version is  ([a-z]+[0-9]? )*

Comment: @ArashFarahani if I were you I'd look into Stata's documentation what standard does Stata follow, I always get into trouble when testing regex to greg on the web because Js used standard

Comment: @Unihedron I don't understand why you have to down vote my answer when Arash is no planing to hack himself, and he commented himself that regex performed well on his data set

Comment: To take Unihedron's comment into account you can enclose my regex in (?>regex) on one of him links its says that this is a remedy to backtracking if that becomes a problem